# Artificially make one commit point to another one after manual merge?

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-commit

I was in such a git state:

after `git checkout outer`:

```
* 2df9c6b (HEAD -> outer) Ready for merging
* 161c98f Working on new stuff..
* faec47b Welcome to branch `outer`
* d2166d0 last common commit
...
```

after `git checkout master`:

```
* 82c6303 (HEAD -> master) Go on doing stuff
* d2166d0 last common commit
* ...
```

After having run `git merge outer` with no conflicts, I came out with something
like:

```
* 6ebd696 (HEAD -> master) Merge branch 'outer' into master
|\
| * 2df9c6b (outer) Ready for merging
* | 82c6303 Go on doing stuff
| * 161c98f Working on new stuff..
| * faec47b Welcome to branch `outer`
|/
* d2166d0 last common commit
...
```

However. The automatic merge turned out not to be what I actually wanted to
have. So I ran `git reset 82c6303 --hard` to start over with:

```
git merge outer --no-commit
... fixing stuff, merging on my own ..
git add *
git commit -m "Merged branch 'outer' into master"
```

What I have now is:

```
* 3d1250b (HEAD -> master) Merge branch 'outer' into master
* 82c6303 Go on doing stuff
* d2166d0 last common commit
* ...
```

Which is: commit `3d1250b` is like I wanted it to be, but it does not point to
`2df9c6b` anymore. How can I make it point to `2df9c6b` in order to make it
clear what happened? Would it even mean anything?

Comment: Which commits does `3d1250b` point to?

Comment: @DavidDeutsch `3d1250b` points to `82c6303`, whereas `6ebd696` used to point to both `82c6303` and `2df9c6b`. It seems like the "merge commit" is a special commit..

Comment: `3d1250b` should indeed point to those two commits as well; are you sure you did not do a `git merge --abort` or anything between `git merge outer --no-commit` and `git commit`?

Comment: @DavidDeutsch Hmm.. only `vim`, `git log`, `git diff` I think.. Do you think it is likely that I just have broken my merge operation somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So unless you did something funky between `git merge outer --no-commit` and `git commit -m "Merged branch 'outer' into master"`, I have no idea why your commit was not recorded as a merge commit (i.e. why it doesn't have two parents). But, assuming that `3d1250b` really contains the snapshot as you would like it after the merge, the following will make an "empty" commit that points to `3d1250b` and `2df9c6b`, which is a "correct" history: `git merge outer --strategy ours`.